# How to save a randomforest in scikit-learn？

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

Actually there is a lot of question about persistence,but i have tried a lot using `pickle` or `joblib.dumps` . but when i use it to save my random forest i got this:

```
ValueError: ("Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'SIZE_t' but got 'long'", <type 'sklearn.tree._tree.ClassificationCriterion'>, (1, array([10])))
```

Can any one tell me why?

some code for review

```
forest = RandomForestClassifier()
forest.fit(data[:n_samples], target[:n_samples ])
import cPickle
with open('rf.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    cPickle.dump(forest, f)
with open('rf.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    forest = cPickle.load(f)
```

or

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
joblib.dump(forest,'rf.pkl') 

from sklearn.externals import joblib
forest = joblib.load('rf.pkl')
```

Comment: please post some example code.

Comment: Both solution give the same error?

Comment: Are you using the same 32/64 bit python to save/load? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21033038/scikits-learn-randomforrest-trained-on-64bit-python-wont-open-on-32bit-python

Comment: oh,i forget i have use not the same bit.thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is caused by using different 32/64 bit version of python to save/load, as [Scikits-Learn RandomForrest trained on 64bit python wont open on 32bit python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21033038/scikits-learn-randomforrest-trained-on-64bit-python-wont-open-on-32bit-python) suggests.

Answer (score 1):

Try to import the `joblib` package directly:

```py
import joblib

# ...

# save
joblib.dump(rf, "some_path")

# load 
rf2 = joblib.load("some_path")
```

I've put the full working example with the code and comments [here](https://mljar.com/blog/save-load-random-forest/).