# I cant load ML model into flask tried using joblib and pickle

Tags: python, flask, scikit-learn, pickle

Im facing an issue with loading ML model (RandomForest ML model) into flask.
i have tried both libraries joblib and pickle both generate the same erro

```py
model = pickle.load(f)
  File "sklearn\tree\_tree.pyx", line 606, in sklearn.tree._tree.Tree.__cinit__
ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'SIZE_t' but got 'long long'
```

here is my flask app

```py
# all necessary libraries are imported 

# Use pickle to load in the pre-trained model.
with open(f'model/model_2.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    model = pickle.load(f)

# model = load('model/model.joblib')

app = flask.Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')
```

My Jubyter Notebook:

```py
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as nm
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

df =  pd.read_csv('phishing _urls_v2.csv')
columns = ['No_of_dots','Length_of_host','contains (exe)','redirect (//)',]
labels = df['malicious'].values
features_2 = df[list(columns)].values
X_train_2, X_test_2, y_train_2, y_test_2 = train_test_split(features_2, labels, test_size=0.30)
model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=52)
model.fit(X_train_2,y_train_2)
model_predict_2 =model.predict(X_test_2)
accuracy = confusion_matrix(y_test_2, model_predict_2)
print (accuracy)

from joblib import dump, load
dump(model, 'model.joblib') 

import pickle
pickle.dump(model, open('model_2.pkl','wb'))
```

I load the model in Jubyter Notebook and works perfectly fine

```
model = pickle.load(open('model_2.pkl','rb'))
print(model.predict([[1,10,0,0]]))
[0]
```

I couldn't figure out the issue.

Comment: Two questions: 1) does the import error _only_ occur in Flask? I.e. can you reimport your model and successfully execute it in a Jupyter NB after exporting? 2) I don't see an import statement for pickle in the Flask app code. Could you post the complete code for the Flask app?

Comment: In addition, are you running your Flask app in the same environment and with the same versions of sklearn as you do when you create and serialize your model in Jupyter?

Comment: Potentially useful thread on dumping/loading on different architectures that could at least explain your issue: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/7891

Comment: Im using the same version of sklearn in Flask and for JubyterNotebook . I tried to load another model Linear Regression its works fine.

Comment: I have load the model in  Jubyter Notebook and works fine. for Flask thats what I have so far, the issue is with Loading the model

Comment: And just to be sure, you've checked this question as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27595982/how-to-save-a-randomforest-in-scikit-learn/27596667 You might want to post a few of the threads that you've checked and ruled out in your original question. It seems like you can rule out sklearn version mismatch and host system architecture mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

Thank Mayosten for your hints.
the issue was that the python version used in Jubyter Notebook is 32bit while in Pycharm was 64bit.

to verify use this command

```
import ctypes
print (ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_voidp))

# 8 for 64bit and 4 for 32bit
```

Comment: Bravo! Was going to further suggest to export the exact environment you’re using in Conda to a virtual environment, but looks like you found something similar.