# Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'SIZE_t' but got 'long long'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, machine-learning

I developed 3 ML models in `spyder`, they are Linear Regression, Polynomial Regression, and Random Forest Regression. In `sypde`r all of them worked well. However when I deployed on Django for creating a web app, Random Forest was raising " ValueError: Buffer type mismatch, expected 'SIZE_t' but got 'long long' ". (I tried removing `randomforest` and the other two models worked well).

**Check this out first:-**
[image: ValueError Image of CMD]

**Model Developed in Sypder**

```
"""****************** Import Lib ******************"""
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

"""****************** Loading dataset ******************"""
boston = load_boston()
dataset = pd.DataFrame(boston.data, columns=boston.feature_names)
dataset['target'] = boston.target

"""****************** Data Preprocessing ******************"""
""" Data Analysis """
# Check Null
dataset.isnull().sum()
# Calculate X and y 
X = dataset.iloc[:,:-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:,-1].values.reshape(-1,1)
# train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=25)
""" Visualizing Data """
corr = dataset.corr()
sns.heatmap(corr, annot=True, cmap='Blues')
sns.pairplot(dataset)

"""****************** Regression Models ******************"""
""" Linear Regression """
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor_linear = LinearRegression()
regressor_linear.fit(X_train, y_train)
cv_linear = cross_val_score(estimator = regressor_linear, X=X_train, y=y_train, cv=10)

""" Polynomial Regression """
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
poly_reg = PolynomialFeatures(degree = 2)
X_poly = poly_reg.fit_transform(X_train)
regressor_poly2 = LinearRegression()
regressor_poly2.fit(X_poly, y_train)
cv_poly2 = cross_val_score(estimator=regressor_poly2, X=X_poly, y=y_train, cv=10)

""" Random Forest Regression """
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
regressor_rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=500, random_state=0, n_jobs=-1)
regressor_rf.fit(X_train, y_train.ravel())
cv_rf = cross_val_score(estimator=regressor_rf, X=X_train, y=y_train.ravel(), cv=10)

"""****************** Measuring the Error ******************"""
models=[
        ('Linear Regression', cv_linear.mean()),
        ('Polynomial Regression (2)', cv_poly2.mean()),
        ('Random Forest Regression', cv_rf.mean())
        ]
cv_scores = pd.DataFrame(data=models, columns=['Model','CV Score'])

"""****************** Dump ******************"""
from sklearn.externals import joblib
joblib.dump(regressor_linear,'regressor_linear_jb')
joblib.dump(regressor_poly2,'regressor_poly2_jb')
joblib.dump(regressor_rf,'regressor_rf_jb')
```

**Django Implementation Code**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json
from django.http import JsonResponse
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
# Create your views here.

# ML Code

regressor_linear = joblib.load('./models/regressor_linear_jb')
regressor_poly2 = joblib.load('./models/regressor_poly2_jb')
regressor_rf = joblib.load('./models/regressor_rf_jb')

# ML Code End

def predict(request):
    temp_data = [
                 0.16902,
                 0,
                 25.65,
                 0,
                 0.581,
                 5.986,
                 88.4,
                 1.9929,
                 2,
                 188,
                 19.1,
                 385.02,
                 14.81,
                 ]
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame(temp_data).transpose()
    predict = {}

    # Linear Regression
    predict['Linear Regressor'] = round(regressor_linear.predict(temp_df)[0, 0], 2)

    # Polynomial Regression.
    regressor_poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
    temp_df_poly = regressor_poly.fit_transform(temp_df)
    predict['Polynomial Regressor'] = round(regressor_poly2.predict(temp_df_poly)[0, 0], 2)
    
    # Random Forest Regression
    predict['Random Forest Regressor'] = round(regressor_rf.predict(temp_df)[0],2)
    
    return JsonResponse(predict)
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21033038/scikits-learn-randomforrest-trained-on-64bit-python-wont-open-on-32bit-python

Answer (score 0):

**Switch environment for Django to anaconda and this will be resolved**

Jupyter notebook was using anaconda environment while Django was using different environment which was installed on system
*(Major problem --> one was 32 bit while other was 64 bit)*